# WordPress Woocommerce 3.1.2 - create variable product programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Looking on the Internet, I found many ways to create a variable product, but none of them creates a variable commodity. In the database, entries do not correspond to records created through the admin panel. Help me please!

`WC version`:   `3.1.2` 
`WP version`:   `4.8.3`

Example code from this [site](https://ryanknights.co.uk/insert-woocommerce-products-variations-programmatically/)

`functions.php`

```
<?php 

function insert_product ($product_data)  
{
    $post = array( // Set up the basic post data to insert for our product

        'post_author'  => 1,
        'post_content' => $product_data['description'],
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_title'   => $product_data['name'],
        'post_parent'  => '',
        'post_type'    => 'product'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post); // Insert the post returning the new post id

    if (!$post_id) // If there is no post id something has gone wrong so don't proceed
    {
        return false;
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $product_data['sku']); // Set its SKU
    update_post_meta( $post_id,'_visibility','visible'); // Set the product to visible, if not it won't show on the front end

    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $product_data['categories'], 'product_cat'); // Set up its categories
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'variable', 'product_type'); // Set it to a variable product type

    insert_product_attributes($post_id, $product_data['available_attributes'], $product_data['variations']); // Add attributes passing the new post id, attributes & variations
    insert_product_variations($post_id, $product_data['variations']); // Insert variations passing the new post id & variations   
}

function insert_product_attributes ($post_id, $available_attributes, $variations)  
{
    foreach ($available_attributes as $attribute) // Go through each attribute
    {   
        $values = array(); // Set up an array to store the current attributes values.

        foreach ($variations as $variation) // Loop each variation in the file
        {
            $attribute_keys = array_keys($variation['attributes']); // Get the keys for the current variations attributes

            foreach ($attribute_keys as $key) // Loop through each key
            {
                if ($key === $attribute) // If this attributes key is the top level attribute add the value to the $values array
                {
                    $values[] = $variation['attributes'][$key];
                }
            }
        }

        // Essentially we want to end up with something like this for each attribute:
        // $values would contain: array('small', 'medium', 'medium', 'large');

        $values = array_unique($values); // Filter out duplicate values

        // Store the values to the attribute on the new post, for example without variables:
        // wp_set_object_terms(23, array('small', 'medium', 'large'), 'pa_size');
        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $values, 'pa_' . $attribute);
    }

    $product_attributes_data = array(); // Setup array to hold our product attributes data

    foreach ($available_attributes as $attribute) // Loop round each attribute
    {
        $product_attributes_data['pa_'.$attribute] = array( // Set this attributes array to a key to using the prefix 'pa'

            'name'         => 'pa_'.$attribute,
            'value'        => '',
            'is_visible'   => '1',
            'is_variation' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy'  => '1'

        );
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes_data); // Attach the above array to the new posts meta data key '_product_attributes'
}

function insert_product_variations ($post_id, $variations)  
{
    foreach ($variations as $index => $variation)
    {
        $variation_post = array( // Setup the post data for the variation

            'post_title'  => 'Variation #'.$index.' of '.count($variations).' for product#'. $post_id,
            'post_name'   => 'product-'.$post_id.'-variation-'.$index,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
            'guid'        => home_url() . '/?product_variation=product-' . $post_id . '-variation-' . $index
        );

        $variation_post_id = wp_insert_post($variation_post); // Insert the variation

        foreach ($variation['attributes'] as $attribute => $value) // Loop through the variations attributes
        {   
            $attribute_term = get_term_by('name', $value, 'pa_'.$attribute); // We need to insert the slug not the name into the variation post meta

            update_post_meta($variation_post_id, 'attribute_pa_'.$attribute, $attribute_term->slug);
          // Again without variables: update_post_meta(25, 'attribute_pa_size', 'small')
        }

        update_post_meta($variation_post_id, '_price', $variation['price']);
        update_post_meta($variation_post_id, '_regular_price', $variation['price']);
    }
}

function insert_products ($products)  
{
    if (!empty($products)) // No point proceeding if there are no products
    {
        array_map('insert_product', $products); // Run 'insert_product' function from above for each product
    }
}

$json = file_get_contents('my-product-data.json'); // Get json from sample file
$products_data = json_decode($json, true); // Decode it into an array

insert_products($products_data);
```

`my-product-data.json`

```
[
    {
        "name"        : "T-Shirt",
        "sku"         : "TS1000",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac erat maximus augue accumsan egestas. Quisque posuere augue quis libero molestie posuere.",
        "categories"  : [
            "Clothes", "Mens"
        ],
        "available_attributes": [
            "size", "color"
        ],
        "variations":
        [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "size"  : "Small",
                    "color" : "Red"
                },
                "price" : "8.00"
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "size"  : "Medium",
                    "color" : "Red"
                },
                "price" : "10.00"
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "size"  : "Small",
                    "color" : "Blue"
                },
                "price" : "8.00"
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "size"  : "Large",
                    "color" : "Blue"
                },
                "price" : "12.00"
            }                           
        ]
    }
]
```

After executing this code, a simple product is created.

Comment: if it doesn't create any variable, it should give some warnings. Please enabele wp_debug and check which warnings you are getting. or check apache error log file.

Comment: @Elvin85 nothing, this is the first thing I checked

Comment: Okay. In insert_product_variations function before the first loop (foreach $variations as $index => $variation) do var_dump($variations) and check if coming in data is correct. i guess that there might be some parsing problem which brings some incorrect array data to that final function.

Comment: @Elvin85 You probably did not understand me correctly, all the data that is generated in the script is added, only they do not match the pattern that the wc itself creates. I even included the phpstorm debug and tracked the functions, all the data was created.

Comment: okay, may be there is some misunderstood, but i have solved similar problem 3-4 monthes ago, in one client's development server.  I did some "reverse engineering" for this: 1. Got the latest state in related mysql tables. 2. created simple product  and some variables. 3. Again returned to mysql tables and analyzied which data had been changed there.  4. Then wrote a code which did the same changes programmatically. And it worked.

Comment: @Elvin85 I, too, already thought so to do, but I hoped that perhaps there is the best solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: one more (and probably better) way is using WooCommerce RESTful API. it has native product and variation related functions which do all needed changes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is the part that makes it a variable product:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'variable', 'product_type');
```

Make sure to use `true` for the 4th param to avoid hosing the other terms:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'variable', 'product_type', true);
```

If you look at the code for `insert_product_attributes` you'll see it's actually hosing your "variable" term (I imagine the behavior was different in 2016).

Finally, it might be a good idea to clear the transients for that product:

```
delete_transient( 'wc_product_children_' . $post_id );
delete_transient( 'wc_var_prices_' . $post_id );
```

I just tried it and it imported my variations properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been on the same blog and got frustrated until I got to use the Woocommerce REST API. I think there is no other way to create products with variations without going though the API please follow this [link](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) and save yourself from the frustration otherwise you will search the entire web and wont find anything that works and for some reason many bloggers wont tell you they'll keep telling you that you and your code are the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the professional plugin WP-ALL-IMPORT

it has a woocommerce addon.

Take a look at their video here : http://www.wpallimport.com/woocommerce-product-import/

it will create woocommerce variable products with their attributes based on variables in your json file

it will have everything you want :-)

very nice drag and drop features... saved me alot of time :-)